I have a question about youtube-data-api. It's about audio
I want to query information using the YouTube API. The data I want to query is the audio track information of the video. To explain in detail, when I upload my video with Korean and Japanese audio tracks, I want to obtain "Korean, Japanese" data about the audio track information of the video through the YouTube API.
Is the audio track information I can obtain through the YouTube API? If that's true, I would be grateful if you could tell me which part of the YouTube API document I should check.
Thank you.
I checked the YouTube API document specified below, and did not find the audio track information I wanted in the document.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=en


Just to make sure, may you share an example video id?
